# Is it appropriate to have EntityManager in a bundle class?

Tags: database, jsf, jpa, bundle, resourcebundle

I want to know if it is efficient in JSF to define `EntityManager` and `TypedQuery` in a bundle class that is supposed to read messages from database?
What if I create an instance of a `@Stateless` bean and use its functions that return query results inside the bundle class?

**UPDATE:** Included some code:

```
protected class DBControl extends Control{
@Override
public ResourceBundle newBundle
        (String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
{            
    return new ArticleResources(locale);
}       

protected class ArticleResources extends ListResourceBundle{
    private Locale locale;

    public ArticleResources (Locale locale){
        this.locale = locale;
    }            
    String language = locale.getLanguage();

    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents(){                  
        TypedQuery<ArticleLcl> query = em.createNamedQuery("ArticleLcl.findForLocale", ArticleLcl.class);
        query.setParameter("lang", language);
        List<ArticleLcl> articles = query.getResultList();
        Object[][] allArticles = new Object[articles.size()][3];                
        int i = 0;
        for(Iterator<ArticleLcl> it = articles.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            ArticleLcl article = it.next();
            allArticles[i] = new Object[]{article.getArticleId().getArticleId().toString(),article.getArticleTitle()};
            messages.put(article.getArticleId().getArticleId().toString(),article.getArticleTitle());                    
            i++;
        }
        return allArticles;
    }            
}
```

By the way this code does not work and my entity manager is null. But I wonder am I doing the right thing?

Comment: Maybe my jsf is a bit rusty, but what do you mean by bundle class? ResourceBundle class is all that comes to mind, but it's for holding texts. Also show us some code

Comment: It is a class that extends `ResourceBundle` and has an inner  class that extends `ResourceBundle.Control` class to read messages from database. Please see the update. I've included some code.

Comment: If you were using Seam you could do `Component.getInstance('entityManager')` to get it (after configuring it), but I suppose you want JSF/JEE only solution

Comment: I don't see how `em` is being declared. You say it is null, but how do you retrieve it in your Control?

Comment: I use `EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();`